# How to invoke a python module in Yocto bitbake recipe?

Tags: grpc, yocto, bitbake, recipe

I am working on a linux open-embedded project (Yocto), and I need to use gRPC.

Below are my recipes that try to invoke the gRPC python module. (grpcio-tools)

In local.conf

```
TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK_append = " nativesdk-python3-grpcio-tools"
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " python3-grpcio-tools"
```

Then is my .bb file, I try to add it as Depends.

```
 DEPENDS += " python3-grpcio-tools"
 do_compile(){
   python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc -I ${S} --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. ${S}/tests/rcu_ser.proto
 }
```

But it fails to find the python module during bitbake. Below is the failure code:
[image]

Please teach me how to invoke the python module during bitbake.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, 
I would add "inherit pkgconfig python3native" and change DEPENDS to "python3-grpcio-tools-native" and add RDEPENDS_${PN}  += "python3 python3-grpcio-tools"

Comment: great :) Since my sugessted changes work I added it as a answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use dependency on the host during compile time you must always depend to native version of a recipe. Modify your recipe as following:

```
inherit python3native    
DEPENDS += "python3-grpcio-tools-native"
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "python3 python3-grpcio-tools"
```

Comment: What is the purpose of pkgconfig? And why set RDEPENDS_${PN} if the module should only be used at build time?

Comment: @JanSchatz Which module? python3-grpcio-tools? If the module isn't needed during runtime it can be removed from RDEPENDS_${PN}.. I don't looked into the application in detail

Comment: yes I meant python3-grpcio-tools. The question was about invoking the module inside the recipe. That's why the RDEPENDS irritated me.

Answer (score 1):

This thread helped me so I thought I would share a complete .bb recipe that's working for cross-compiling a proto file into the necessary files for a Petalinux / Yocto Zeus gRPC server using python. I'm no bitbake expert. This installs the resulting pb2 files in /usr/bin and compiles them using python3-grpcio-tools for the target device (which may be an older/different version than what you have on your build machine). The proto file includes protobuf definitions as well as rpc definitions, hence the generated _pb2_grpc.py file.

```
SUMMARY = "My summary."
SECTION = "PETALINUX/apps"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

SRC_URI = " \
  file://my_proto.proto \
"

inherit python3native

RDEPENDS_${PN} = " \
    python3-core \
    python3-protobuf \
    python3-grpcio \
"

DEPENDS += " \
    python3-grpcio-tools-native \
"

do_compile() {
  python3 -m grpc.tools.protoc -I${WORKDIR} --python_out=${WORKDIR}/. --grpc_python_out=${WORKDIR}/. ${WORKDIR}/my_proto.proto
}

do_install() {
  install -Dm 0755 ${WORKDIR}/my_proto_pb2.py ${D}/${bindir}/my_proto_pb2.py
  install -Dm 0755 ${WORKDIR}/my_proto_pb2_grpc.py ${D}/${bindir}/my_proto_pb2_grpc.py
}

FILES_${PN} = " \
  ${bindir}/my_proto_pb2.py \
  ${bindir}/my_proto_pb2_grpc.py \
"
```